# In rails, how to easily reverse a self-referring one to one relation with existing data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, refactoring

I have a rails project which already has a lot of production data. I have a certain table:

```
node:
  id: integer
  follow_node_id: integer
```

Every follow_node has a single parent_node, so this is a self-referring one-to-one relation. Being fairly new to rails, I mistakenly defined the relation like this:

```
has_one :follow_node,    class_name: 'Node', foreign_key: 'follow_node_id'
belongs_to :parent_node, class_name: 'Node', foreign_key: 'follow_node_id'
```

The mistake is obvious. The foreign key defines the `belongs_to` relation, i.e. the `follow_node_id` points to the `parent_node` and not to the `follow_node`.

I want to change this behaviour so that it makes sense again. the relation that I want to end up with is this one:

```
has_one :follow_node,    class_name: 'Node', foreign_key: 'follow_node_id'
belongs_to :parent_node, class_name: 'Node', foreign_key: 'follow_node_id'
```

The only problem is: I got loads of data, and most of the records have their follow_node_id set. What is an efficient way to update all the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll do it like this.

1. Change the source code of the Node model file as described in the question.
   (The relation now works in incorrect direction, meaning that
   `node.follow_node` returns its parent node, and `node.parent_node`
   returns its follow node.)
2. Write a migration that does the following:

   - Create a new integer field (e.g. `tmp_follow_node_id`)
   - For each `Node` record, store the ID of its parent_node in `tmp_follow_node_id`.
     In code:
     `Node.all.each{|n|n.update_attribute :tmp_follow_node_id, n.parent_node.id}`
   - Drop the `follow_node_id` field
   - Rename the `tmp_follow_node_id` to `follow_node_id`
3. Migrate

Answer (score 0):

I think the script looks like:

```
Node.where(follow_node_id: nil).each do |node|
  parent_node = Node.where(follow_node_id: node.id).first
  node.update_attributes(follow_node_id: parent_node.id)
  parent_node.update_attributes(follow_node_id: nil)
end
```

Comment: Nope, this is only going to do a one time change for the nodes that initially have no parent. All the others are still left untouched. It's much more delicate since most of the nodes have both a parent and a child.

Comment: I think you need to add an extra temporary column that has data type Boolean. Toggle it once you fix a record. By this way, you can only change the records based on this field.

Comment: That will also fail, since on any record that has both a parent and a follow, as soon as you copy one over the other, you either lose one of the two, or you screw up the relations of the other objects. You do give me an idea however: I could create another integer column, traverse over all records and copy the (real) follow_id in that column. After that, I drop the original column and rename the new one to the original one.